# "An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext"

Tags: core-data, uikit

How to solve this ?

https://github.com/hamza5645/progress-tracker-.git
full code

Already have a NSFetchedResultsController and a managedObjectContext

in the homeViewModel

[image]

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class HomeViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private var fetchedResultsController:            NSFetchedResultsController<MyList>
    private(set) var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    @Published var myLists: [MyListViewModel] = []
    
    override init() {
        self.context = CoreDataManager.shared.context
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: MyList.all, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            guard let myLists = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return }
            self.myLists = myLists.map(MyListViewModel.init)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func saveNewList(newListName: String, colorCode: String) {
        
        let myList = MyList(context: context)
        myList.name = newListName
        myList.colorCode = colorCode
        do {
            try myList.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }

}

extension HomeViewModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        guard let myLists = controller.fetchedObjects as? [MyList] else { return }
        self.myLists = myLists.map(MyListViewModel.init)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code (as text) where the `NSFetchedResultsController` is initialized rather than an insignificant screenshot.

Comment: What is `MyList.all`?

Comment: its a static var in an extension Code:



extension MyList {
     static var all: NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        let request = MyList.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return request
    }
    
    func save() throws {
        try CoreDataManager.shared.context.save()
        
    }
    
}

Comment: tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading:

Form the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller)

> ### Using NSFetchedResultsController
>
> **Creating the Fetched Results Controller.**
> You typically create an instance of NSFetchedResultsController as an instance variable of a table view controller. When you initialize the fetch results controller, you provide four parameters:
>
> A fetch request. **This must contain at least one sort descriptor to order the results.**.
> ...

Add a sort descriptor.

Edit: And replace

```
self.context = CoreDataManager.shared.context
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: MyList.all, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

with

```
let context = CoreDataManager.shared.context
self.context = context
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: MyList.all, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

Actually you should get a *accessing `self` before having called `super`* error.

Comment: import Foundation
import CoreData


extension MyList {
     static var all: NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        let request = MyList.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return request
    }
    
    func save() throws {
        try CoreDataManager.shared.context.save()
        
    }
    
}



I already have a sort descriptor in the myList+Extension file 
should I add another one in the homeViewModel or what ?

Comment: No, you haven't. `[]` means **no** sort descriptor.

Comment: how to add a sort descriptor 

I have searched and every page I found is how to use sort descriptor with  @FetchRequest and I don't use that

Comment: Please click on the documentation link. There is an example.

Comment: ok I followed the documentation and added a sort descriptor :

  request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey", ascending: true)]

and I still get the same error

Comment: You have to add the key of the Core Data property you want to sort the data by. `NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey` is invalid. For example if there is a `name` property use literal `"name"` or the keypath `\.name` with the `init(keyPath:ascending:)` API.

Comment: where should I add the init(keyPath:ascending:) ?

Comment: It’s just a replacement of `init(key:ascending:)`. A key path is more robust because it’s validated at compile time.

Comment: so it should be like this ?: request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: "name", ascending: true)]

Comment: No, please read my comments. A key path is `\.name` or `\MyList.name`. And please read the edit in the answer.

Comment: ok so its like that : request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

true?

*I did what you said in the edited answer

Comment: Yes, but you should prefer `[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \.name, ascending: true)] `

Comment: I get this error "Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type"

Comment: `[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyList.name, ascending: true)]`

Comment: ok that worked but I still get the same fatal error when lunching the app Thread 1: "An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext"

Comment: Debug your code. Set breakpoints and watch variables. In the screenshot there is another error: Could not load model. You should fix that, too. Maybe it's the cause of the problems.